# Why might it be silly to have a 2-step Wizard?

Tags: wizard, process

[In reference to 'Designing Interfaces'](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/) it's stated that it's silly to have a 2-step wizard. What are the reasons for this and is it **really** all that bad to have a 2-step wizard process?

> In either case, the hard part of designing this kind of UI is striking a balance between the sizes of the chunks and the number of them. **It’s silly to have a 2-step wizard**, and a 15-step wizard is tedious. On the other hand, each chunk shouldn’t be overwhelmingly large, or you’ve lost some benefits of this pattern.

For my interface there is a 2 step process and I feel that in order to visualize that in a recognizable manner it would be best to use a wizard-like interface.

Would this really be *silly*?

Comment: Maybe the way we think about wizards changed over the years. Today it's even getting quite common to create login pages like some sort of 2-step wizard.

Comment: Wizards are silly. Fixing the process so a wizard isn’t necessary is a greater design goal.

Answer (score 2):

I would have worded it as follows:

> In either case, the hard part of designing this kind of UI is striking a balance between the sizes of the chunks and the number of them. **For example, having a 2-step wizard usually loses the benefits of this pattern, and a 15-step wizard is tedious.**

The concepts expressed are still valid, but of course there are exceptions to every rule. The important part is **striking a balance between the sizes of the chunks and the number of them**.

Have you considered progressive disclosure for your situation?

Answer (score 1):

The page have **2011** year in footer - now we have **2020**.

Today, processes are often divided into the maximum number of steps
(however, of course - reasonably - 15 steps is far too much)

Maybe this suggestion is more about having> 2 steps in the process (minimum 3)

but let's consider personality tests - e.g. 16 personalities

[image]

Tests are divided into 10 stages - modern processes to reduce information overload also divide larger parts into a reasonable number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a limit on wizard's steps but common sense, task length, user testing, etc.

Try some A/B testing.
Do users go through the flow easier with the wizard or without it?
Is it shorter / faster, or prevents errors, or it aids the user to gain better focus on the wizard version?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider here is consistency. In isolation, from scratch, designing a system to use a two step wizard *might* lose some of the benefits of the pattern, but if the rest of your product uses a `one page per action` pattern, a two step wizard *may* be the best approach to ensure it feels coherent with the rest of the product.